# How to remove substrings from html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have the following html string:

```
<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 14px;">
   <span class="author-basic">new op
        <span style="font-size: 30px;">tionlab</span> 
   </span<br>>
```

As you can see at the last `</span>` i have a `<br>` nested inside the tag
This `<br>` can appear anywhere in a `<span>` or `<b>` or `<i>` even inside the style attribute.

Is there a way to move the `<br>` outside the tag ? (i, b , span , style ...)

Comment: Well, yes, but how did it find its way there? :) [`.replace(/(<[^<]*)<br>([^<]*>)/gi, '$1$2')`](https://regex101.com/r/cI8uN6/1), I guess. Or if there can be more: [`<br>(?=([^<]|<br>)*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/cI8uN6/2).

Comment: try using a regular expression to clean them... probably using javascript or jquery

Comment: @stribizhev wow, thank you for you fast response, i need this to move the <br> outside of the tag not just delete it. I ended up with this because i am doing some line wrapping in js and it does not know if it is a html tag where it replaces

Comment: Is there always 1 `<br>`? Do you just need to move the `<br>` right after the tag it was in?

Comment: @stribizhev yes, only one per tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DISCLAIMER*: This is a **hotfix**, not a solution. The solution would be to fix your  line wrapping approach.

To move `<br>` tags outside other tags, you can  use

```
<br>([^<]*>)
```

And replace with `$1<br>`.

The regex matches:

- `<br>` - The literal text `<br>`
- `([^<]*>)` - Captures into Group 1 zero or more symbols other than `<` up to `>` and then `>` symbol (assuming you have regular tags without fancy `<% %>` insertions) (this captured text is later back-referenced with `$1`).

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI8uN6/2)

Snippet:

```js
var re = /<br>([^<]*>)/gi; 
var str = '<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 14px;">\n   <span class="author-basic">new op\n        <span style="font-size: 30px;">tionlab</span> \n   </span<br>>';
var subst = '$1<br>'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
alert(result);
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you very much. With this answered i will post a solution to a wrapping problem id had and i will link you there too :D. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to use something like `jQuery` and select the `<span>` object and insert with a

```
$('selector').after($('<br/>'))?
```